# Gps, Sensors and wake

Tags: java, android, gps, sensors, wakelock

I have a program that reads and writes all the sensors values ​​file, but when you turn off the screen stops the listener on the sensors and the record on txt file.
I already tried with the wake lock, but with little success, I want to know if you have ideas or if I have to resort to a wake to keep me always on the monitor, let me know.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved?

Try onResume and LocationListener

Answer (score 1):

You better should use a Service for listening to the sensors. I did so with my Sports Tracker app and ist works fine.

Answer (score 0):

At least the GPS system  (LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates) is working with a wakelock when the screen is turned off. I don't know about the other sensors. (you tagged GPS with your question)

Comment: yes yes Gps ok, can you give me an example of code and where i put it?

Comment: I put it in a service, which implements LocationListener. The Service is created in the onCreate of the Activity and calls back into the activity each time the location changes.